# Calling asynchronous function in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm having some trouble understanding asynchronous functions. I've read the chapter in [Mixu's Node Book](http://book.mixu.net/ch7.html) but I still can't wrap my head around it.

Basically I want to request a ressource (using the node package `cheerio`), parse it for valid URLs and add every match to my redis set `setname`.

The problem is that in the end it's only adding the first match to the redis set.

```
function parse(url, setname) 
{
    request(url, function (error, response, body) 
    {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
        {
            $ = cheerio.load(body)

            // For every 'a' tag in the body
            $('a').each(function() 
            {
                // Add blog URL to redis if not already there.
                var blog = $(this).attr('href')
                console.log("test [all]: " + blog);

                // filter valid URLs
                var regex = /http:\/\/[^www]*.example.com\//
                var result = blog.match(regex);
                if(result != null) 
                {
                    console.log("test [filtered]: " + result[0]);

                    redis.sismember(setname, result[0], function(err, reply) 
                    {
                        if(!reply) 
                        {
                            redis.sadd(setname, result[0])
                            console.log("Added " + result[0])
                        }
                        redis.quit()    
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

I'd be very grateful for pointers on how I'd have to restructure this so the redis.sadd method is working with the correct result.

The output of the current implementation looks like:

```
test [all]: http://test1.example.com/
test [filtered]: http://test1.example.com/
...
Added http://test2.example.com/
```

So it's adding the test1.example.com but not printing the "added" line, and it's not adding the test2.example.com but it's printing the "added" line for it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is caused by `redis.sismember()` being asynchronous: when its callback is called, you have already overwritten the `result` variable so it will point to the last value it had, and not the value at the moment at which you called `redis.sismember()`.

One way to solve that is to create a new scoped variable by wrapping the asynchronous function in a closure:

```
(function(result) {
  redis.sismember(setname, result[0], function(err, reply) {
    ...
  });
})(result);
```

Another option is to create a partial function that's used as callback:

```
  redis.sismember(setname, result[0], function(result, err, reply) {
    ...
  }.bind(this, result));
```

The second issue is, I think, caused by `redis.quit()` being called, which closes the Redis connection after the first `sadd()`. You're not checking `err`, but if you do it might tell you more.

Comment: Thanks, I added the closure and moved `redis.quit()` to the end of the parse function and now everything is working as expected.